# How can I exempt a regex that starts with a special letter and has a character restriction from a special word?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

It can be 8 characters starting with 'SB' or 8 characters starting with '6' but how can I exclude this second one from being `'66666666'`.
What I wrote for the 1st and 2nd cases works, but how can I add this exception to the one that starts with 6?

```
^(SB)\d{6}$|(6)\d{7}$
```

Comment: Maybe with `^(SB\d{6}|6(?!0+$)\d{7})$`? What is the regex flavor?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Negative Lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It's non-capturing, so doesn't consume the text, only asserts what's next.

```
^(?!6{8})(SB|6\d)\d{6}$
```

Comment: so what should I add if I want to improve it in particular:
If numbers or letters can be entered after SB or after 6.

Comment: ^(?!6{8})(SB|6\d)\w{6}$ this one worked.

Comment: @emrahuz `\w` matches underscores, too. Use `^(?!6{8})(SB|6\d)[\da-zA-Z]{6}$`